# Spring data JPA: How to SELECT, if not found then create?

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, acid

Are there any concise way in Spring data JPA to perform:

1. Select a record by a field
2. If found then return it
3. If not found then create a new one and return it

atomically?

Does `@Transactional` help on this? (I mean create a method, mark it `@Transactional`, perform select, if/else inside)

BTW What is the general pure SQL way to solve this problem? (Let's assume MySql DB.)

Answer (score 4):

There is no pure SQL for what you want to achieve, though you can find vendor-specific solutions. However you can easily achieve this with using `Transactional`:

```java
class EntityService {
    private final entityRepository;

    // constructor omitted

    @Transactional
    public Entity getOrCreate(Entity entity, Long entityId) {
        return entityRepository.findById(entityId)
            .orElseGet(() -> entityRepository.save(entity));
    }
}
```

Comment: What if thread1 & thread2 both found nothing and reach the point `orElseGet` simultaneously? They both save (insert) the same data

Comment: If you have a race condition and you want to create a new entity with a unique field, only one of the saves can finish while the other would fail with an exception, such as `ConstraintViolationException`.

Comment: So should the Entity's field I wanna search by (I didn't mention in the question it's a primary key) have `@Column(unique=true)`?

Comment: Primary keys are unique by default - that's the purpose of a PK, it uniquely identifies a row in a table. I would say 9 out of 10 times you don't have to worry about concurrency here, unless your use-case is really special for some reason. In the very rare case when a race condition occurs here (which believe me, is going to be very rare), the request will just fail and the user can retry again, your database will stay in a consistent state.

Comment: Yes, sure primary key is unique by default. So if I wanna search by another field I need to mark the field `@Column(unique=true)` is it enough? (and then mark `getOrCreate` method with `@Retryable` to let the second thread try again and find) ?

Comment: You might be better off asking this question in a new thread, since it's not really applicable here. If you were to search based on a field that's not unique, you would get a list of entities instead of a single one, where `getOrCreate` doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: So in case of constraint unique field it seems @Transactional is redundant, isn't it? What purpose it serve here? save method is atomic by itself isn't it?